# Paid iOS app for free only to those users who download other free app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes-store

I've got 2 iOS apps

1. My app1 is a paid app.
2. My app2 is a free app.

I want to offer the app1 for free only to those users who download the app2. In the app2 I want to add a link (or something) for downloading app1 for free.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No Apple has not solutions for this and is not possible. Apple only allows you to give a way an app with a promo code. But these are limited and not meant for this.

Comment: I think you can do this, by using OTA process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. There *might* be something you can do with App Bundles (launched with iOS 8) but I don't think you can have a zero price.

A slight variation on your question: if your first app was free with an IAP, you could unlock the IAP by checking for the presence of app2. It's possible that this falls fowl of some of Apple's rules, though.